# Android update UI from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

Good day,

I want to update an image button in my UI from another thread. below is my code that i run in my mains threads onCreate() method.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connected_icon);
            if (netConnection.IsConnected()) {
                // Change icon to green
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_small);
            } else {
                // Change icon to red
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_small);
            }
            try {
                // Sleep for a second before re_checking.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

No when i run this i gen an error int he LogCat saying i cannot update the UI from annother thread.

I remember reading soem where once that this is the case so that you don't get multiple threads updating the same UI object at once.  But how can i achieve this. i am sure there is a work around?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate. There are many such questions. Use the search.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly acces UI components from the thread.
The correct way to do this is by creating a handler

```
 final Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 

     } 
 };
```

And send messages to UIThread with

```
 Message msg = new Message();
 //TODO: add stuff to message
 mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

inside your Thread.

This or use an AsyncTask instead and do the updates from inside of pre, post or progressUpdate methods

Answer (score 1):

UI Elements should be updated only from the UI thread. Use an async task to do background word, and modify the UI in onPostExecute, which runs on the UI thread